How do I echo get_post_meta, wrapped with an HTML tag?
I'm hoping someone can help. I have a custom field for WooCommerce products but I need to wrap the output in an HTML tag.
Please could someone help correct this?
I know it's not the correct syntax, but this is what I have tried to do and hopefully you can see what I'm trying to achieve:
echo '<p> get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_textarea', true ) </p>';


The correct syntax is: echo '<p>'.get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), '_textarea', true).'</p>';
